# ng-model within ng-repeat not updating reference object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-material

In my controller, I have an object:

```
$scope.selectedMap = {
    map: '', mapDesc: '', stops_json: "", stopLength: []
};
```

The **stops_json** key in this object holds another object, that looks like this:

```
{
  desc: "PRG-BUD-HR-PAY",
  stop1:"DEPT",
  stop2:"ACCT",
  stop3:"ACCT2",
  stop4: 158,
  stop5:"CCT",
  stop6:"CCA",
  stop7: 156
}
```

I'm using this child object in an ng-repeat, and generating inputs with it for each stop:

```
<p class="row col-md-12">
  <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>{{ selectedMap.stops_json.desc }}
</p>
<div class="row col-md-12 float-left">
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="stop in selectedMap.stops_json" ng-if="!$first" ng-model="stop" class="col-md-12">
        <label>Stop&nbsp;{{ $index }}:</label>
        <input class="col-md-8 float-left mapStops" ng-model="stop" aria-label="Route Stop Description">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

My issue is, that when I change the value of the input tags, the **stops_json** object does not change. I was under the impression that it was supposed to, since that is the object that is modeled. I am clearly mistaken, can anyone educate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems to mention first:

- [The notation for iterating over objects with `ng-repeat` is `(key, value) in obj`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)
- If you choose to use object iteration with `ng-repeat` then your `ng-if` dependent on `$first` is non-deterministic (i.e. iterating in key definition order is not guaranteed)
- Applying an `ng-model` binding on the `ng-repeat` with the intention of making its constituents editable is incorrect—the models of each item should be have `ng-model` applied instead

I've created a stripped down example of your snippet to demonstrate making the repeated inputs able to change the `stops_json` model.

[See here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/6PyVnxcdpXg6SCHLAktH?p=preview)

Basically, you need to ensure the `input` elements inside the `ng-repeat` directly bind to your `stops_json` model in order for any edits to affect it.

Also, note that all any numeric properties should use the `type="number"` variant of `input`, otherwise any edits will set the values to strings instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful! I'll give it a go this morning and report back

Comment: Now that I've had time to really look at this in depth, I have to say this is a really great answer. Thank you again!